# how to draw custom shapes using a simple texture in libgdx?

Tags: java, opengl-es, libgdx

I want to draw custom static shapes in my game just like the angry birds done:
[image: angry birds]

but the problem is that the texture is in square shape.

[image: static ground]

how we can tell to the "SpriteBatch" to draw shapes with some vertices? does anybody has some ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html):

> A SpriteBatch is used to draw 2D rectangles that reference a texture (region)

So essentially, this method does not allow you to specify any other geometry than a rectangle. However, there is a [draw method](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html#draw%28com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture,%20float%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29) that allows you to specify the four coordinates of the "rectangle" and turn it into something else. You'd've to decompose the geometry into smaller pieces that fits this *primitives*. Looks like this method doesn't lend itself to geometry changes.

Better you [create a mesh](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/MeshColorTexture) and just draw it. The mesh does not support triangulation, so use the [ObjLoader.loadObj*](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/loaders/obj/ObjLoader.html) methods to load a mesh in [Alias Wavefront OBJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) format. Specifying the geometry shouldn't be a hassle; the article links to some example files.

Comment: Thanks for your good advices.
But there is a problem: I use camera and I configured my spriteBatch to use metric viewport. 
And the mesh does not support matrix projection. so if I use mesh.render(..) to draw, it will not support the camera (moving with camera) and the size of it will not metric.
Do you have any idea about this problem?

Comment: @Aliaaa You mean, `SpriteBatch` contains the Projection and ModelView matrix? Have a look [at the next example](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectionViewportCamera), you will need to apply the matrices on your own.