# How to draw custom polygon in libgdx?

Tags: box2d, draw, libgdx

How to draw custom polygon from vertices in libgdx? I want to draw any box2d bodies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a similar question before:

[how to draw custom shapes using a simple texture in libgdx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547897/how-to-draw-custom-shapes-using-a-simple-texture-in-libgdx)

Then I used Mesh class to draw custom shapes.